# Chef-solo: deploy: access to release_path

Tags: ruby, deployment, chef-infra

I have following Chef cookbook:

```
deploy "/home/prj" do
  repo "https://path_to_repo"
  user node.project_owner
  group node.project_owner
  symlink_before_migrate({})
end
```

How can I access to the provider's release path? In my case in will be: /home/prj/releases/20120506125222/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where you want to access the release path. "Inside" the resource, i.e. the callbacks, that's easily possible using something iike

```
deploy "/home/prj" do
  before_migrate do
    gemfile = File.read("#{release_path}/Gemfile")
  end
end
```

Outside of the resource, you don't have the release_path variable available. You can however use the `current` symlink which points to the currently deployed version, i.e. the last release:

```
current_path = "home/prj/current"
release_path = File.readlink(current_path)
```

Most of the time, you can to things directly in the `current_path` without having to resort to resolving the symlink target.

That said, you typically don't want to actually do things in there directly. Instead, you are encouraged to generate additional files in the shared directory (i.e. `/home/prk/shared`) and let chef symlink those files into the release during deployment. That's exactly what `symlink_before_migrate` is for. That way, you don't need to actually know the release path yourself but can let chef handle that for you.